# При вводе ниже написаного текста в браузере ничего не отображается

Tags: php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$name = "Александр";
$age = 25;

echo "$name"

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А вы куда этот текст вводите?

Comment: при вводе куда, стесняюсь спросить? В стиральную машину?

Comment: в нотепад++ в файл index.php

Comment: @ААА однит только файл indfex.php - это еще не сайт, и серверный код в нем не начнет выполняться  сам по себе

Answer (score 1):

Видите ли, PHP работает немного не так, как вы себе представляете. Нельзя просто открыть php-страницу в браузере. Сначала её должен обработать интерпретатор PHP. Обычно сначала поднимают веб-сервер, на который ставят PHP и кладут страницу, только после этого её открывают в браузере. В каноничном случае это [LAMP](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP), но, судя по уровню вашей осведомлённости, вам больше подойдёт [Денвер](http://www.denwer.ru/). И учите матчасть. Хотя бы [Википедию](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) почитайте, я уже молчу про литературу.

Comment: У меня денвер установлен и запускаю через него.localhost/php